# Adding the timestamp to SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display the timestamp in the SQL query. Can someone help me out, please!? :D

```
SELECT company, COUNT(dmy) FROM `AdTracking` WHERE company = 
'twitter' AND dmy BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') GROUP BY DAY(dmy)
```

**Here is the SQL query** - Notice it does not have the timestamp!
[image]

**Here is the table:**
[image]


Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `dmy` column in select, see updated query

```
SELECT company, COUNT(dmy), dmy FROM `AdTracking` WHERE company = 
'twitter' AND dmy BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') GROUP BY DAY(dmy)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for what I asked! ... but maybe you can help me out with my last issue -  I'm using http://goo.gl/6f8iUT and trying to get it to show each day (for a month) in a Line Chart display with my table shown above! Any idea!?  - I got the other charts to work but just not the Line Chart! Thank you! I really appreciate it a lot!

Comment: have you looked at their [examples](http://www.chartphp.com/demo/#database/line.php), that's exactly what you need

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just don't get their example. I'm very new to php and I'm having a fun time messing around with php but this is making me want to pull out my hair! haha